# Problems with my .swf Files

Tags: windows-7, swf

Today I got a little problem with my files, I tried (accidentaly) to open my `.swf` file with notepad.

Now I don't know how to fix it because  every `.swf` file is with a notepad icon on it.(I want to make it default how it was)

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need to change the file association with the file.

You do this by pressing the start button (the windows icon in the task bar) and choose Default Programs

Then choose Associate a file type or protocol with a program

Another way is to right click on a `.swf` file and open with -> and then choose program. Here, you can check the check box to make it default